# Maven proxy configuration not working

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy

I know there are already many questions on this subject but somehow I can't work out how to use maven 3.0.5 behind a proxy.

The settings.xml file inside my .m2/ folder looks like this

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>http-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyname</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>Domain\user</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

I also added wagon-http-lighteweight-2.2.jar to MAVEN_HOME/lib/ext.
I'm using maven inside eclipse, but it's showing the correct settings file in eclipse maven properties.

Despite having all these settings I still get the following error message after importing a spring boot project:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for <ProjectName>:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

Comment: Have you executed with the debug option on? `mvn -X install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running maven with the -X switch like Little Santi suggested I saw that the proxy is not the problem but the company I work in uses lokal maven repositories which I had to include.

I added these repositories and mirrors to my settings.xml and now it's working fine.